# Two-Step estimation

Tags: regression, model, logit

I am currently trying to fit a model that has the following properties: 

(1) data for several years

(2) two decisions/equations (probably involved): 

(a) one that explains an initial choice of product (binary variable that describes whether you take the same product or not)

(b) one that explains how much you will pay for this new product. 

My explanatory variables are all product specific (new and old product) and I would like to find a model that can simultaneously estimate both purchase equations. However, I am not sure, which model I should use. Do you have any good suggestions? (I use STATA and R). 
My data is structured as follows: 
- data from individuals that indicated (1) product they had purchased the last period, and (b) the product they purchased now. 

- I have a set of variables that describes each of the products (e.g., price, product design and so on)

- the whole dataset is over several years but the individuals only were observed one time (where they specificied both products

- overall I have 10000 observations (with each the currently purchased product and the previously purchased product 
I thought about those equations: 

y1 <- x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 

y2 <- x1 + x2 + x3 + x4 + y1

y1 would specificy whether the same product was chosen and y2 the price of the new product o alternatively the difference in price between the old and the new product. I am not sure, whether such a binary equation 1 can be easily implemented and whehter I must fix that this has been the first equation. After all, the consumers could also think first about getting a more expensive product (from the same company or just a different and more feature-rich product) and than that they whether they want to change this product. E.g., Consumers could get the same bike, but just with more expensive features, --> y1 = 0, y2 > 0 or  consumers could switch to another bike company and then decide whether to pay more or less. Thus, the equations might not be fully independent.. Not sure what to do, any help appreciated!

Comment: So that this question can be answered, please describe your data and the kinds of "purchase equations" (whatever they might be) that you have in mind.